# How to use python to autofill excel file by scanning key words from the other excel file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

[image]

How to use python scan this excel file and only pick up values under specific keyword and autofill to a blank excel file?

[image]

This is the result table

Comment: Please include your own code.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check [`xlsx_cells`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/io/#janitor.io.xlsx_cells) from [janitor](/questions/tagged/janitor) to make this kind of *reshaping*.

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), one option is to shift the values (*horizontally*) to the very left as much as it's possible.

```
df = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", header=None)

def lshift(df):
    out = df.copy()
    for r in range(len(out)):
        col = len(out.columns) - len(out.iloc[r].dropna())
        out.iloc[r, col:] = out.iloc[r].dropna()
        out.iloc[r, :col] = np.nan
    return out
​​
out = (
        lshift(df)
            .drop_duplicates()
            .dropna(how="all", axis=0)
            .dropna(how="all", axis=1)
            .pipe(lambda x: x.rename(columns=x.iloc[0]))
            .iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Output :
​

```
print(out)

  Stock                 Date Open High Low Close Adj Close Volume
0     1  2023-01-01 00:00:00   50   50  50    50        50     50
1     2  2023-01-01 00:00:00   60   60  60    60        60     60
```

Input used (*spreadsheet*) :

[image]